# Running composer as a normal user instead of a root/super user on CentOS 7

Tags: php, composer-php

When i try to install a php composer dependency regardless of from where i start, it always asks for super user privileges.
I've followed many recommendations for running without root privileges, but it still asking for super privileges.

I've changed the owner of composer to user; I did not find any /.composer in root ou normal user home. I've removed and reinstalled the composer but it still running into the same problem.
I'm running CentOS 7, i've found tips for other operating systems but dispite of all, and similarities of the question, none has solved the problem.

Comment: `sudo chmod +rx $(which composer)`